# Android same category but different size devices?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app. I've done much so far, but I've some problems. So far, I've compiled the app on **Nexus 5** and I've designed the layout for that device. I know that, I should have different layout folders for different screen categories, but my problem is that, for example, my app works pretty good on Nexus 5, but not good on **Nexus S**.

And I also know that those 2 devices are in the same layout category.

How can I solve this issue? I want a layout for Nexus S which differs Nexus 5.

Note: Please, do not comment documentation links. I've read them all, but couldn't solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between px, dp, dip and sp on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

From [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> - ldpi (low) ~120dpi
> - mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
> - hdpi (high) ~240dpi
> - xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
> - xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
> - xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Using desnity:

*Nexus 5* is **~445** dpi => belong to `xhdpi` category.

*Nexus S* is **~233** dpi => belong to `mdpi` category.

So you can use `layout-xhdpi` directory for **Nexus 5**, and `layout-mdpi` directory for **Nexus S**.

---

**UPDATE**

Using dimensions:

*Nexus 5* is **1080 x 1920** pixels. => `layout-1080x1920` directory

*Nexus S* is **480 x 800** pixels. => `layout-480x800` directory (or just the default one)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Rami. But the result is the same; xhdpi was chosen for both devices.

Comment: @user3163150  I don't have physical devices for test, but that's strange. Give a try with dimension, check my update.

Comment: I use Nexus S as emulator and Nexus 5 as physical device. As of now, I have **layout-480x800** folder and **activity_login.xml** in it. Running with Nexus S emulator, I get the view from layout-xhdpi folder @Rami

Comment: Remove *activity_login.xml* from *layout-xhdpi* folder, add it in *layout-480x800* and another one in *layout-1080x1920* .

Comment: Again the same layout. **layout-480x800** @Rami

Comment: I just tested it in my 2 emulators and works fine. Make sure you have *activity_login.xml*  **ONLY** in *layout-480x800* and *layout-1080x1920* directories.